# Lerp to target position, but only within a radius

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 3D game but my player can only move on the X and Y axis.  I have a player with an attached camera following my mouse, but I only want it to follow up to a max radius distance from Vector3.zero, even if my mouse is beyond those bounds.

I have tried repositioning the player to the max distance on radius every frame it tries to follow the mouse outside its bounds, but this causes camera jitters even in LateUpdate.

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        firstTouchPos = movementCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        playerPos = transform.position;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        Ray currentTouchPos = movementCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 direction = currentTouchPos.origin - firstTouchPos.origin;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Vector3.zero);

        if (distance >= radius) {
            targetPosition = direction.normalized * radius;
        } else {
            targetPosition = playerPos + direction * touchSensitivity;
        }

    }

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * followSpeed);
}
```

I'm thinking there must be a way to clamp the positioning of the player to a radius so that I don't have to "leash" him back by repositioning him through code every frame.

Comment: It maybe better to calculate and clamp the velocity of the object such that it can't reach the end of the radius.

Comment: Try `Vector3.ClampMagnitude()`, I think that might help.

Comment: Thank you @FantasmicGalaxy! I watched a video on ClampMagnitude and was then able to apply it and achieve the desired outcome

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and mark it for posterity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use Clamp Magnitude.

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        firstTouchPos = movementCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        playerPos = transform.position;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        // targetPosition will follow finger movements
        Ray currentTouchPos = movementCam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 direction = currentTouchPos.origin - firstTouchPos.origin;
        targetPosition = playerPos + direction * touchSensitivity;
    }

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * followSpeed);
    transform.position = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(transform.position, radius);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try using `Vector3.ClampMagnitude()`.